# What is the difference between lm(offense$R ~ offense$OBP) and lm(R ~ OBP)?

Tags: r, dataframe, prediction, lm, predict

I am trying to use R to create a linear model and use that to predict some values.  The subject matter is baseball stats.  If I do this:

```
obp <- lm(offense$R ~ offense$OBP)
predict(obp, newdata=data.frame(OBP=0.5), interval="predict")
```

I get the error: Warning message: 'newdata' had 1 row but variables found have 20 rows.

However, if I do this:

```
attach(offense)
obp <- lm(R ~ OBP)
predict(obp, newdata=data.frame(OBP=0.5), interval="predict")
```

It works as expected and I get one result.  What is the difference between the two?  If I just print OBP and offense$OBP, they look the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case, you get this if you print the model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = offense$R ~ offense$OBP)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  offense$OBP  
    -0.1102       0.5276
```

But in the second, you get this:

```
Call:
lm(formula = R ~ OBP)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)          OBP  
    -0.1102       0.5276
```

Look at the name of the coefficients. When you create your newdata with `newdata=data.frame(OBP=0.5)`, that not really make sense for the first model, so newdata is ignored and you only get the predicted values with the training data. When you use `offense$R ~ offense$OBP`, the formula has just two vectors at each side, with no names associated to a `data.frame`.

The best way to do it is:

```
obp = lm(R ~ OBP, data=offense)
predict(obp, newdata=data.frame(OBP=0.5), interval="predict")
```

And you'll get the proper result, the prediction for `OBP=0.5`.

Comment: Thanks.  Awesome answer.  I wasn't aware of the, data=offense formulation.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference---you get the same coefficients.

But some programming styles are better than others -- and attach is to be avoided, as is the more verbose first form.

Most experienced users do

```
 lm(R ~ OBP, offense)
```

instead.